# Create archive for offline conda environment installation

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am currently facing this problem: We developed a Python project that we currently deployed with the complete Anaconda distribution.

We want to make this more individual by creating a custom environment that we could then share. We have chosen to use Conda as a fitting tool.

I have already researched how to create and export an environment in Conda using the *.yml file, but on installation this requires internet connectivity for downloading the packages and files.

Is there also another way to create say **an archive that already contains all the files needed from the environment.** We could then just pass around that archive file with all dependencies included. How would this be achieved?

It would also be really helpful if you could just point me into the right direction.

Comment: this might be relevant: https://github.com/conda/constructor

Comment: This seems to include the whole conda installation, do I understand that correctly? So, let's say I wanted to deploy an update of the packages, would I then need to deinstall everything and run the new installer? Thanks anyhow!

Comment: If you include the conda package in your constructor, you should be able to use it to update any and all packages in your installed instance.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried [constructor](https://github.com/conda/constructor), but I see two other options, namely

### conda-pack

[conda-pack](https://github.com/conda/conda-pack) allows you to package an installed environment.

For an installed environment run s.th. like

```sh
conda pack \
  -n MyEnv \
  -o MyEnv.tbz2 \
  --format tbz2 \
  --compress-level 9 \
  --n-threads 4
```

You'll get a `.tbz2` file (or whatever archive/compression you did choose). Copy that to the target location and run

```sh
mkdir $envBaseDir/MyEnv    
# The directory name is the environment name.
cd $envBaseDir/MyEnv
tar -xf /path/to/MyEnv.tbz2
source bin/activate
conda unpack
```

No network access is needed for these steps (tried it with my network turned off).

The two most relevant [caveats](https://conda.github.io/conda-pack/#caveats) seem to be

1. An environment created with `conda unpack` cannot be packed again. So keep the original archive.
2. You cannot create (new) archives for very old environments, because the package cache of the environment's packages need to be present.

Note that I have no experience with recreating (`conda unpack`) environments from old archives. The archives really only contain the stuff installed in your `envs/MyEnv` environment directory, so there may be situations in which the Conda base environment may be too divergent. This may limit the reproducibility of the archived environment. Therefore, ...

### Container

You can create the environment in a container. This solution has a number of disadvantages

- steep learning curve of working with containers (creating and running them). You'll find a number of tutorials and examples of Dockerfiles that use Conda with your search engine.
- discussions with your security-aware admins, if want to run your containers in a multi-user cluster environment
- rather big containers

But dependent on your needs these disadvantages may be outweighed by the exceptionally good and (most likely much longer-term) reproducibility.